# How to create a Shelf Like View in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

I am new ios app development.

I have created a shelf like view but after adding custom button to add books, And after scrolling over table view the Buttons gets disappered.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom cell with background without any books in it.. 
Some thing like this..

Please note I have just cropped your image to explain you..

[image]

In your custom cell place 4 buttons at regular interval.. These will be your books.. 
On clicking those buttons you can open PDF. You can further manipulate your books accordingly.. 
This is the most basic idea..

For rows in table.. U can return

```
if(noOfRows%4!=0)
  return (noOfRows/4)+1;
else
  return (noOfRows/4);
```

and for cellforrowatindex method..U can keep a counter to keep a count to start with.. 
Hope this will help you more..

Comment: Dimp i m facing some problem here, the Buttons are not getting alligned properly. Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: @Micel Dont write any code related to button frames in ur custom class. Create buttons in xib and then connect them to xib.  Since I think you were writing frame codes in init of custom cell.. I think that should be in layoutsubviews.. Try connecting in xib that would definitely solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

I'd start off with [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView), that's an excellent grid control for iOS, supporting animated adding, deleting, editing and sorting. You could draw a custom background below the grid, and that's it for the basics.

Comment: ayoy:Thanks 4 reply, Its good tutorial but can you please tell me how to create a view shown above so that it should look like a shelf. And also i wann add books to the shelf.

Comment: he just told you "supporting animated adding, deleting, editing and sorting. You could draw a custom background below the grid" otherwise you manually make views and animate coordinate changes on those views.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but:

There now exists an open source control called GSBookShelf, that already offers the shelf-like look together with reordering animations etc.

Here is the source: https://github.com/ultragtx/GSBookShelf

I hope this helps future readers getting a more complete overview over the ways they could implement a shelf-list like the one seen in iBooks.